# How to make a slice from an matrix in an env in R

Tags: r, env

So have an an env that I put data.frame in

`dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
termCount = c(".94", ".96", ".98" ,".99")
freqMatrix <- new.env()
spam <- new.env()
for (v in termCount){
    # Remove sparse terms to get a managable number of terms.
    dtmEnv[[v]] <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, as.numeric(v))
    # Convert the document term matrix to a standard matrix.
    freqMatrix[[v]] <- as.data.frame( as.matrix(dtmEnv[[v]]))
    # Normalize the frequency matrix: 0 if absent, 1 if present.
    spam[[v]] <- (freqMatrix[[v]] > 0) + 0 # Add 0 to convert from logical to int.
}`

Then however when I try taking slices from my data frame I get an error

```
for (v in termCount){
  trainData <- (spam[[v]])[folds$subsets[folds$which != i], ]
  testData  <- (spam[[v]])[folds$subsets[folds$which == i], ]
 # ... more stuff hear ...
 }
```

Error in spam[[v]] (from #8) : wrong arguments for subsetting an environment

## Print the resulting accuracies.

What am I doing wrong? 
Is there a cleaner way of doing such an iteration for different values in termCount?

Comment: Should `for (v in ternCount){` have `termCount` not `ternCount`?

Comment: ...in the second `for` loop

Comment: Yes you are correct although it was not what triggered the bug. I eventually just rewrote the thing and it worked. Is there a better way to do such repeated iterations in R?